# Русский язык в школах Украины

Tags: преподавание, образование

С каких классах школы учат русскому языку на Украине?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть школы русские и украинские. Русские имеются только в крупных городах Юго-Востока, по 5-10 на город, на Западе их нет вообще. В русских школах русский язык изучают с 1 класса. В украинских школах русский язык считается иностранным, когда в 5 классе начинают вводить иностранный язык, у родителей на собрании спрашивают, какой язык будет учить их ребёнок - русский или английский. Все выбирают английский, ведь по-русски они и так говорят. Но в школе его не учат, правил не знают. При Януковиче всё изменилось, стали русский учить и в украинских школах с 5 класса независимо от английского. (А теперь, видно, опять грядут перемены: английский вводят не с 5, а со 2 класса, обязателен второй язык - немецкий, а русский под вопросом). Русской литературы нет вообще ни в русской, ни в укр. школе, она частично идёт в курсе зарубежной литературы, урывками между Шекспиром и Сервантесом. В украинских школах русские тексты идут на украинском языке. Пушкину, например, уделено 45 минут, 1 урок, (ещё и на укр. языке!) за все годы учёбы в укр. школе. В вузах русская филология находится на факультете иностранных языков и тоже литературы отдельно нет, только в курсе зарубежной литературы.

Comment: Интересно, что в украинских вузах филология преподаётся так: английский язык и литература, немецкий язык и литература, французский, испанский, польский, турецкий и т.д. - язык и литература. И только русский язык, как сирота, без литературы.

Answer (score 0):

В Киеве есть русские школы. Пока. С преподаванием русского языка с 1 по 11 классы и ведением остальных предметов на русском языке. В началке (с 1 по 3 кл., про 4-й не знаю) р. яз. составлял 3 урока в неделю, украинский тоже 3 урока в неделю.